# Is there proxyfier like tsocks, but with arguments to specify socks server?

Tags: command-line, proxy, socks

Is there proxyfier like tsocks, but with arguments to specify socks server?

E.g.

```
# xtsocks --socks 127.0.0.1 9050 --command wget -O - http://google.com
```

Problem with configuration file.

To use different proxy for different task you must always modify configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se) does what you want:

`curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 google.com`

Also, you should be aware of the new [torsocks](https://github.com/dgoulet/torsocks), 
which replaces tsocks.  However, this does not provide the ability you have asked for.